# How can I declare an array for ChildContent RenderFragment

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

I have wrote 2 components:

- MyLine.razor
- MyTable.razor

Here is how I want to use this components:

```
<MyTable>
  <MyLine />
  <MyLine />
  <MyLine />
</MyTable>
```

Here is what I've wrote for MyTable.razor:

```
@code
{
   [Parameter]
   public RenderFragment ChildContent { get; set; }
}
```

It works, but I want to count all "MyLine" components.

Here is what I've tried:

```
   [Parameter]
   public RenderFragment<MyLine> ChildContent { get; set; }

   [Parameter]
   public RenderFragment<List<MyLine>> ChildContent { get; set; }
```

But it does not work.

Any idea ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside `MyTable` component define a list that will keep track of `MyLine` children and two methods for adding and removing items from the list. Also cascade `MyTable` component to the child components.

**MyTable.razor:**

```
<CascadingValue Value="this" IsFixed>
    @ChildContent 
</CascadingValue>

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public RenderFragment ChildContent { get; set; }

    private readonly List<MyLine> _lines = new();

    public void AddLine(MyLine line)
    {
        if (!_lines.Contains(line))
        {
            _lines.Add(line);
            StateHasChanged();
        }
    }

    public void RemoveLine(MyLine line)
    {
        if (_lines.Contains(line))
        {
            _lines.Remove(line);
            StateHasChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

Then inside `MyLine` component you can use the cascading parameter to get a reference to the parent component. `MyLine` will pass itself to the parent list  when it's initialized and will remove itself from the parent list when it's disposed.

**MyLine.razor:**

```
@implements IDisposable

...

@code {
    [CascadingParameter]
    public MyTable MyTable { get; set; }

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        MyTable.AddLine(this);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        MyTable.RemoveLine(this);
    }
}
```

Now inside parent component you can do `_lines.Count` to get the result you want.

**BlazorFiddle:** https://blazorfiddle.com/s/v6uj2o6m

Also I would like to point to an example in the documentation for cascading values and parameters where it states:

> `TabSet` component *can provide ***itself*** as a cascading value* that is then picked up by the descendent `Tab` components.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/cascading-values-and-parameters?view=aspnetcore-6.0#pass-data-across-a-component-hierarchy

Sometimes it is useful to cascade the parent component to its child components and there is nothing wrong in doing it.

Comment: Thanks but I want to use MyTable like this: <MyTable><MyLine /><MyLine /></MyTable> ...

Comment: Here is a BlazorFiddle demonstration: https://blazorfiddle.com/s/v6uj2o6m

Answer (score 0):

Not sure who needs to know what, so I've wired in an event to raise when lines are added or removed from the collection.

First a data object to hold the data you want to cascade (don't cascade a component):

```cs
public class MyTableData
{
    private List<MyLine> _lines { get; set; } = new List<MyLine>();

    public IEnumerable<MyLine> Lines => _lines;
    public event EventHandler? LinesChanged;

    public void AddLine(MyLine line)
    {
        if (!_lines.Contains(line))
        {
            _lines.Add(line);
            this.LinesChanged?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        }
    }

    public void RemoveLine(MyLine line)
    {
        if (_lines.Contains(line))
        {
            _lines.Remove(line);
            this.LinesChanged?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        }
    }
}
```

Now MyLine.  I'm not sure if your doing anything dynamically with the adding and removing lines so I implemented a remove in `Dispose`.  Dispose should get called by the render if it removes a line instance from the render tree.

```cs
@implements IDisposable
<h3>MyLine</h3>

@code {
    [CascadingParameter] private MyTableData? TableData { get; set; }

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        if (this.TableData is not null)
            TableData.AddLine(this);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (this.TableData is not null && this.TableData.Lines.Contains(this))
            TableData.RemoveLine(this);
   }
}
```

And `MyTable`.  It registers an event handler to ensure the component gets rendered (displays the correct number of lines) when `this.TableData.Lines.Count()` changes.

```cs
@implements IDisposable

<h3>MyTable</h3>
<CascadingValue Value=TableData>
    @this.ChildContent
</CascadingValue>
<div>
    Lines: @this.TableData.Lines.Count();
</div>

@code {
    [Parameter] public RenderFragment? ChildContent { get; set; }

    public MyTableData TableData { get; set; } = new MyTableData();

    protected override void OnInitialized()
        => TableData.LinesChanged += this.OnLinesChanged;

    private void OnLinesChanged(object? sender, EventArgs e)
        => this.InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged);

    public void Dispose()
        => TableData.LinesChanged -= this.OnLinesChanged;
}
```